# Voice to text in python

Tags: python, voice-recognition

Lets say I want to give input in Hindi or any other language in voice
And it will give an output in English  (text). How can I do that?
What I know:
I know how to transfer voice to text.

E.g.
Information given : language=hindi
Input: kese ho (in voice)
Output: how are you? (In text)

Answer (score 0):

Voice-to-text uses ML/AI so if you want to code it yourself check out algorithms such as PLP features, Viterbi search, Deep Neural Networks, discriminative training, WFST framework. If you just want to use a library I would recommend [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/). Then for translation, you would want to use [translate](https://pypi.org/project/translate/).

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of python, for this multimodel type, [Jina](https://github.com/jina-ai/jina) seems something worth exploring.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So as I see, you will need Speech Recognition + Translation. If you're open to using API, you can check this APIs below.

1. [Convert Speech to Text](https://apyhub.com/utility/speech-to-text)
2. [Translate Document](https://apyhub.com/utility/text-translator)

You have to build a logic to stitch both to have a response you want. Stil, It's some thing which might not work, but worth to try out.